# Odoo web client. Unable to select an html element with the jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-9

The following refer to Odoo v9 enterprise version.

**Task**: When opening the timesheet form from Main Menu -> timesheets, send a .click() event on the Details tab so that the details tab opens.

**Problem**: When I use the selector to select the element I get nothing in return. ( I have confirmed that the selector I use is correct for the dom element that interests me)

In accordance with the official documentation for the odoo web client, I have extended the `web.FormView` widget, and overriden it's start method. From taking a look at the examples, it seems to me that when the `start` method is invoked the `DOM` has already been rendered.

When I use `console.log(this)` from within the start method I can see an object that has the DOM in the `$el` variable.

I am trying to make a selection using a jquery selector but I am unable to get my object.

My custom widget js:

```
odoo.define('t9397.form_override', function(require) {
    "use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var web_widget = require('web.FormView')

    var FormWidgetOverride = web_widget.extend({

    start : function(record) {
        console.log('overridden')
        console.log(this)
        this.$("a[data-toggle='tab']:contains('Details')").click()
        $("a[data-toggle='tab']:contains('Details')").click()// trying both
        return this._super()

        }
    })
    core.view_registry.add('form', FormWidgetOverride);
});
```

The `DOM` object I want to send a click event to:

```
< a data-toggle="tab" disable_anchor="true" role="tab" href="#notebook_page_22">Details< /a >
```

My knowledge of promises, `Jquery`, and especially the web client of `odoo` is somewhat rather limited. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start()` may perform rendering tasks including asynchronous procedures, so it's necessary to wait while it finishes it's execution. As per [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html#openerp.Widget.start):

> A widget is not guaranteed to work correctly until its start() method
>   has finished executing. The widget's parent/creator must wait for a
>   widget to be fully started before interacting with it.

Normally, start should return a [Deferred() jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and if start() itself is implemented properly in super, than you can wait it using the Deferred object received from it's call:

First case to use for a simple code as yours:

```
start : function() {
    var sup_ready = this._super();
    sup_ready.done(function(){
        //your code:
        console.log('overridden');
        console.log(this);
        this.$("a[data-toggle='tab']:contains('Details')").click();
        $("a[data-toggle='tab']:contains('Details')").click(); // trying both
    });
    return $.when( sup_ready );
    }
});
```

Second case, to use for asynchronous procedures and more complicated code:

```
start : function() {
    var sup_ready = this._super();
    var me_ready = $.Deferred();
    . . .
    sup_ready.done(function(){
        . . .
        . . .
        //finally Resolve or Reject your deferred object:
        //Resovle:
        me_ready.resolve(); //use it if all go ok
        // *OR* Reject (in case something go wong) to indicate failure:
//      me_ready.reject();
    });
    . . . 
    return $.when( sup_ready, me_ready );
});
```

Note that I put `me_ready.resolve()` inside `sup_ready.done()` but it is NOT absolutely necessary and in general it may be other way around i.e. you can Reject or Resolve `me_ready` outside of this `sup_ready.done()`, you can resolve or reject `me_ready` deferred object anywhere in your code.

The second case above does not apply to your current issue, but it's a pitfall to avoid in the future, just in case.

As an **alternative** to the `start()` way you choose, consider also an [`events` property](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html#openerp.Widget.events) of the widget and check if you can apply it to your case...